# Regular Expression, how to split with | and avoiding to split when \ is before

Tags: java, regex

I have the next text

```
 aaa|bbbb|cccc|dddd\|eeee|ffff
```

and i want to split by | and excluding when | is preceded by \ and obtain

aaa

bbbb

cccc

**dddd\|eeee**

ffff

Thanks.

ps : i tried using some regexp generator (for example http://txt2re.com/ ) but frankly regexp is anything but friendly.

update: finally i give up. Regexp is not fast (i did a benchmark), neither is clear (in comparison with a function that everybody can follow), then i skip it and now i am using real code.

Comment: It sounds like you want a negative lookbehind assertion.

Comment: Why would it be `dddd\|eeee` and not `dddd|eeee`?

Comment: If your pattern is that simple, you could also use just iterate through the characters, and only split if you find the pipe `|`, but the preceding character is not a backslash `\\`. I'm not sure how your input String is constructed, but if you have control over that, you could also just not use \| in that position, but use a different character, if that's an option.

Comment: @ Gabe i dunno how i can be downranked by a single question but happens (trolls? angry dev?). Personally i disagree with any downvotes.  @ Tim Cooper i try to keep the backslash, i don't want to delete it. @ normalocity since backslash is the de facto standard then i want to keep it and use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried to add this as a comment to eyelidlessness's answer, but don't know how to format it there...

Anyhow, eyelidlessness answer looks correct to me:

```
    String str = "aaa|bbbb|cccc|dddd\\|eeee|ffff";
    String[] tokens = str.split("(?<!\\\\)\\|");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
```

which prints:

```
[aaa, bbbb, cccc, dddd\|eeee, ffff]
```

Comment: Aye, that's true, this won't handle escaped backslashes, but I guess that depends if that's a concern or not. Maybe they won't exist in whatever domain this poster is working in.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
(?<!\\\\)\\|
```

If you want to allow backslash-escaped backslashes, you can use:

```
(?<!(?<!\\\\)\\\\)\\|
```

So given the string `aaa|bbbb|cccc|dddd\|eeee\\|ffff`, the split would be:

```
    aaa
    bbbb
    cccc
    dddd|eeee\*
    ffff
```

* Or `dddd\|eeee\\` if you're not stripping escape-backslashes for some reason.

Edit: not familiar with Java regular expression flavor, added escapes per ratchet freak's comment.

Comment: you might wanna do it in java syntax `"(?<!\\\\)\\|"`

Comment: thanks but it don't work : value1: aaa|bbbb|cccc|dddd  value2:
|eeee|ffff, i think i will take the scenic route, replacing "\|" for a safe character, then splitting by "|" and replacing back to "\|"

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `split()` for this. (You could if Java supported indefinite repetition inside lookbehind assertions. But it doesn't.)

Better collect all the matches between `|`s:

```
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\|])*");
Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    matchList.add(regexMatcher.group());
}
```

This correctly splits `aaa|bbbb\\|cccc|dddd\|eeee|ffff\\\|ggg\\\\|hhhh` into

```
aaa
bbbb\\
cccc
dddd\|eeee
ffff\\\|ggg\\\\
hhhh
```